# Hexadecimal to String PDF

Tags: php, pdf, hex

I have a hexadecimal value that I need to convert back to a pdf and save it. I have tried to convert to string and display but browser keeps failing to load the pdf. I am retrieving the pdf from a web service and I know the hex is valid.

Below is the function I am using to convert and then to display:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.pdf"');

function hex2str($func_string) {
$func_retVal = '';
$func_length = strlen($func_string);
for($func_index = 0; $func_index < $func_length; ++$func_index) $func_retVal .=    chr(hexdec($func_string{$func_index} . $func_string{++$func_index}));

return $func_retVal;
}

$hex = hex2str($string);

echo $hex;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it isn't base64_encoded?

Comment: Please indent your code properly for your and our sake. This is not [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: yes I have checked that it isn't supplied as base64 by the documentation.

Comment: The string I am getting back is extraordinarly long. But here is a portion in case someone can tell me if there is a better way to try to convert and display? Again any help is very much apprecicated.

   '0x255044462D312E340A0A322030206F626A'

Comment: Well, that hex definitely looks like a PDF, since it starts with '%PDF-1.4' when converted to a UTF-8 byte array